# same LWC component to be fired on a button press

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have developed a LWC component for stopwatch wrapped in Aura component which I use I Utility bar.
The component is working great. I am currently stuck at a part where i need a button, on the button press another instance of same stopwatch shall be displayed to the user so that the user can use as many (more than 2, depends on the user) stopwatches at same time. Can anybody guide me how this can be achieved?
Also I am not getting what more info must be posted here so that it will be easy to understand the issue.

Comment: The other instance of the same stopwatch will be displayed where?

Comment: @NagendraSingh right below the first stopwatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can have is a parent component and inside that use an iteration to print multiple child components.

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="add" onclick={addNew} ></lightning-button>

    <template for:each={cmpList} for:item="ele">
        <div key={ele.id}><c-stopwatch></c-stopwatch> </div>
        <!-- might need some CSS here how you want to stack these components-->
    </template>
</template>
```

Js file will be

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Testcmp extends LightningElement {

    @track cmpList = [{id: 1}];
    // id can be any attributes you want to pass to child cmp so that you can identify different stopwatches.
    addNew(){
        this.cmpList.push({id : this.cmpList.length +1});
    }
}
```

you can add remove logic by passing ID from parent to child.